# clone for Hp-UX?

Tags: virtualization, clone, hp-ux, clonezilla

we have HP-UX installed on HP Itanium hardware. As per HP hp-ux will not run on intel board. and vmware also not supporting hp-ux as guest OS.
Is there any way to clone the hp-ux and it will run on intel m/c using visualization or something else?

Answer (score 3):

None of the major hypervisors will do this as what you're trying to do isn't virtualisation but *emulation*.

There is a fairly basic IA-64 to x86 emulator [HERE](http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/983) but I think you may struggle to find something really useful.

Answer (score 0):

[QEmu](http://qemu.org) can emulate IA64, and can virtualize in certain situations (likely not applicable here).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to virtualize HPUX is using HPiVM, HP integrity virtual machine which basically is an HPUX which act as a host for (normally) other HPUX guests.

If you want learn HPUX try to find an old server in eBay. If you want emulate for production environments don't use any other virtualization solution than HPiVM ;)

Answer (score -3):

HPUX Now runs on Intel platform like the HP Superdome 1 and 2.

Comment: HP Superdome 1 and 2 use IA-64 processor architecture and not x86.

Comment: @NoNoNo why the down vote? I said Intel Platform. IA64 is an all new architecture for 64 bit CPUs, promoted and developed by Intel and HP. This architecture is very powerful, designed for very high end servers. The CPU chips alone sell for around $3000 each, not including the motherboard and other peripherals. So technically, it's an Intel platform right? And by the way, there is an x86 port which is NOT released to the public. Better check your facts first!